# Why is it necessary to pass callback as an argument when it is already available

Tags: javascript, callback

In Javascript

Why is it necessary to pass callback function as an argument to the calling function while it is already available in the global scope?

Comment: So that the target function knows which globally available function to call? (If that isn't a satisfactory answer: care to point out what you mean, with example code?)

Comment: "while it is already available in the global scope" --- while *what* is available in the global scope?

Comment: @zerkms : I meant to say the  called function is already available in the global scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have a scenario something like this:

```
function gotUserName(name) {
   alert('User name is: ' + name);
}

function getUserName(id) {
   getAjax('/getuser/' + id, gotUserName);
}

function getAjax(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Where you're asking why you have to pass `gotUserName` as a callback, and then call `callback`, instead of calling `gotUserName` directly from the `getAjax` function?

While that would certainly be possible, the simple answer is that `getAjax` can be used for many more ajax requests than only get username. You pass the callback not to make it available, but to avoid having to hard-code it inside `getAjax`.